# I can't pass the information of a TextField from a class to another

Tags: java, arraylist, jbutton

I'm trying to make a registration program, so a created a little window where I would type the name to be registered and save it in another class when I press a button. But the other class isn't pulling the info from the string.

```
public class Puxarclasse 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new ClassePuxar();
        
        ArrayList lista = new ArrayList ();
        lista.add(ClassePuxar.stringTeste);
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassePuxar implements ActionListener
{
    private static JButton botao;
    private static JTextField tfPuxar;
    public static String stringTeste;
    public ClassePuxar () 
    {
        JFrame frame  = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         tfPuxar = new JTextField();
         botao = new JButton ();
        
        frame.setSize (400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        tfPuxar.setBounds(50,60,300,20);
        botao.setBounds(150,110,100,20);
        botao.addActionListener(this);
        
        panel.setLayout(null);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(tfPuxar);
        panel.add (botao);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        stringTeste = tfPuxar.getText();
        tfPuxar.setText ("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're working in an event driven environment, that is, at some point in the future, something will happen and then you can respond to it.

You're mind set seems to be in a procedural workflow (where things happen in a linear timeline sequence)

For example...

```
new ClassePuxar();
    
ArrayList lista = new ArrayList ();
lista.add(ClassePuxar.stringTeste);
System.out.println(lista);
```

By the time the window (associated `ClassePuxar`) is on the screen, the `ArrayList` code will have already run, so the user's had NO opportunity actual enter any information.

You have to basic options:

1. Use an observer pattern of some kind to generate events when the data changes in some meaningful way
2. Use a modal dialog. See [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Oh, and `static` in this context is NOT a cross object communication mechanism and implemented this way is a bad idea.

`null` layouts are also a bad idea.  Make the time and effort to learn how to use of the [various layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

## Modal dialog...

So, you could replace just about all your code with just...

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Show me the input", "Input", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (input != null) {
    ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
    lista.add(input);
    System.out.println(lista);
}
```

And you should get the basic desired result.